# Base64 Encoded secrets

Tags: encoding, base64, azure-data-factory

Our SQL passwords as base64 encoded in Key Vault. Is there a way to have data factory decode the secret before it connects to SQL? I looked at the `base64ToString` function but I can't find the correct syntax for data factory to first get the secret from kv before decoding it.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory will get the secret from key vault(through secret name) to connect the Azure SQL database directly.
[image]

In linked service key vault settings, it doesn't support the expression and function `base64ToString` with `Add dynamic content`.
[image]

In one word, there isn't a way to have data factory decode the secret before it connects to SQL. We can  not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, while reading the SQL Password from Azure Key Vault directly in linked service, it cannot decode the value. However, we can use below approach using web activity along with copy activity that enables us to decode password from Key Vault while accessing SQL database. The output can be marked as "Secure" in web activity that enables us to ensure password is not displayed during execution of pipeline. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities) for accessing secrets using web activity.

[image]